# "Source not found" when debugging Android code in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've been stuck on this issue for a long time and can't seem to find a fix.  I have a method where I want to retrieve the HTML source of a website, but every time I run the client.execute step, Eclipse outputs "Source not found".  I can hit a breakpoint prior to that step and whether I try to "step over" that line or just hit "go" I still receive "Source not found".  This is my method

```
private void getQuestions()
{
    try 
    {

        URI url = null;
        try 
        {
            url = new URI("http://google.com");
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(url);

        // THIS LINE CAUSES SOURCE NOT FOUND
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

        System.out.println("HttpResponse received");

    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

In my AndroidManifest.xml file I've also added the following prior to my  tags

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I've found some people with similar problems and tried their fixes with no success.  I've added my application name to my source path and placed it above Default.

[image: source]

I've also moved my Application to be bottom of my build paths

[image: build path]

I am running Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Juno Service Release 1

Comment: This usually means the app has crashed, you can link to the source code for HttpClient with [Eclipse debugging "source not found"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1960158/1267661).  However this isn't the reason your app crashed, open the LogCat window to see the stack trace.

Comment: @Sam [here is a screenshot of my logcat](http://i.imgur.com/LDEYkvb.png), but it doesn't seem to provide anything of use?

Comment: Check the solution in the bottom - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9161430/using-httpget-on-android.  It may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have created one demo, and its working fine in mine.. please check it, i think it might help you..

```
URI url = null;
        try 
        {
            url = new URI("http://www.google.com");

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = "";
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            try 
            {
                while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) 
                { 
                    total.append(line);
                }
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.w("Html",total.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and i am using this in my Manifest file.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and i think you should put your "jsoup-1.7.2.jar" file in libs directory and add jar in project from this libs directory. and just select checkbox to "check (true)" of your jar in Java Build Path dialog. ( It's not necessary but it should checked). like..

[image]

Comment: I have the jsoup.jar file in my libs folder.  Here is my [Package Explorer] (http://i.imgur.com/rbAsItc.png).  Also, checked everything in my [Java Build Path](http://i.imgur.com/1zVscCT.png).  Still no luck.  I'm completely baffled.

Comment: Ah! I'm finally catching an Exception "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" after adding catch (Exception e) to my code.  I haven't figured out why I have an exception yet, but this is much much better!